# Efficient inline implementation of nCk in Perl

Tags: perl, math

Is there any existing implementation that compute this in Perl?

```
 nCk (n choose k), or n!/(k!*(n-k!))
```

That only returns a number, not list of combination.

Comment: Why would non-CPAN be important? You can always look at the source of anything on CPAN.

Comment: If it isn't on [CPAN](http://cpan.org) it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Math::Counting](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math%3a%3aCounting) defines the necessary functions. You can copy and paste the following and use it without any
external modules:

```
sub combination {
    my( $n, $r ) = @_;
    return unless defined $n && $n =~ /^\d+$/ && defined $r && $r =~ /^\d+$/;
    my $product = 1;
    while( $r > 0 ) {
        $product *= $n--;
        $product /= $r--;
    }
    return $product;
}
```

However, for arbitrary precision, you should use [Math::BigInt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math%3a%3aBigInt). Again, you can use the function from [Math::Counting](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math%3a%3aCounting):

```
sub bcomb {
    my( $n, $k ) = @_;
    $n = Math::BigInt->new( $n );
    $k = Math::BigInt->new( $k );
    my $r = $n - $k;
    return $n->bfac() / ($k->bfac() * $r->bfac());
}
```

Comment: `Math::BigInt` already provides this functionality with `bnok()`, e.g. `Math::BigInt->new($n)->bnok($k)`. no need to call the `bfac()` routines yourself